# How to make parallel dashed stroke lines?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, stroke

When I try to offset my line with dashed stroke, the original and the offset path do not run in sync. The dashes should be side by side, but they are not. Screenshots:

[image]

[image]

Can someone help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The quick answer is that you can't.  Not with simply applying the dashed line to a stroke.  Illustrator doesn't align dashes based on the document grid, it's based on the line and nodes.

If you want them to line up, you will have to manually separate either the outside or the inside line to shift the start point for the dashes.

*** Edit

> Billy Kerr's answer below is MUCH better!

[image: example]

Answer (score 11):

Make a pattern brush like this from alternating 2 black filled rectangles, and 4 rectangles with no fill and no stroke.

[image: Alternating Rectangles]

Here's an example of the brush with settings, which I then applied to a path.

[image: Path Example]

For the corner settings, make sure to select "Auto-Slice".

[image]

Comment: OMG! Of course! 

Comment: or that. Never even thought of that!  It does get a little weird on the corners though.

Comment: @Alith7 - Yeah, the corners mess up a bit, however it would be possible to create custom corners with a bit more work.

Comment: @BillyKerr Will you accept my edits for one that doesn't look funky on the corners?

Comment: @Alith7 Sure - go ahead and edit it if you want. :)

Comment: I did, just waiting for approval.

Comment: @Alith - The problem is it doesn't really show an example path with corners to see what it will actually look like. Could you perhaps show that too?

Comment: @BillyKerr I have one in my second image. Do you mean one with the stroke line selected so you can see the nodes?

Comment: @Alith7 Oh I see it now. Sorry. I approved it the edit. Looks good!

Comment: thanks!  Collaboration makes perfect! ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can try also this trick. It's a workaround and has its own problems like other workarounds.

[image]

1. The original curve with a narrow stroke
2. The stroke width is changed to 3 mm
3. A copy is made with 3,75 mm wide stroke and dashes
4. Version 2 is lifted on top and aligned with ver. 3. Ver. 2 is used as an Opacity Mask for 3.

You can edit stroke widths and dashing after releasing the opacity mask.

Comment: That's not a bad solution either.